# Riding the Boston train (T) on Shabbat - written evidence?

Tags: history, shabbat, vehicles-transportation

I've long heard 'urban legends' of halachically observent Jews in Boston many years ago riding the train ('the T') on Shabbat. Does anyone have any written evidence of such a practice? (I'm not looking for the halachic reasoning, as per [another question on this site](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12331/riding-the-subway-on-shabbat), rather for evidence for a sociological phenomenon in the halachic Jewish community.)

Comment: Rabbi Rakeffet discusses Jews in the Bronx riding the subway on Simchas Torah, and a listener eventually found written proof of it.

Comment: I heard the T could only be ridden outbound on Shabbat, because it used to be that you only paid for inbound trips.

Comment: ...the T isn't actually a form of transit, so I think it'd be okay.  Remember, their first priority is safety. ;)

Comment: Is it just me, or does anyone else think that this question would be more appropriate to be asked over at the History SE?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, it may well also be on-topic there, but as it's about the history of Jewish practice, it's definitely on-topic here, and I would expect there to be greater likelihood that one of our experts would know of a source for this information than one of theirs.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, explain how I enter the T at North Station and exit it at Harvard Sq. then…

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about Boston, but I know that at one time Jews on the mainland in Hong Kong would take a ferry to the island where the synagogue was located.  Instead of paying for the ferry as usual, they purchased tickets in advance.  I have myself seen such a ticket and printed on it the words "only to be used by Jews on the Sabbath".

Comment: This might be a better comment than an answer.

Comment: Related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26952/kayak-or-canoe-on-shabbos