# May one paddle a canoe (or ride in one) around in a lake or pond on Yom Tov?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, vehicles-transportation

Suppose one lives next to a lake or a pond and has a canoe (or a kayak or other non-motorized, sail-less rowboat) that is kept docked at the water.  May one use it on Yom Tov?  Is this melacha?  Does it count as "traveling" if one has no destination and is simply paddling around and returning to his point of departure?  What if one is not paddling but simply riding along?  Would the answers be different on Shabbat?

Comment: Also see the interesting summary of a responsum of the Chavos Yair on MiYodeah [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26954/9947).

Answer (score 3):

The [Shulchan Aruch 339:7](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.339.2-7?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) implies that one is *only* allowed to enter a docked boat if he is not moving it around:

> סְפִינָה, אִם הִיא יוֹשֶׁבֶת בְּקַרְקַע הַיָּם וְאֵינָהּ שָׁטָה כְּלָל, מֻתָּר לִכָּנֵס בָּהּ; וְאִם הִיא קְשׁוּרָה כְּמִנְהַג הַסְפִינוֹת הָעוֹמְדוֹת בַּנָּמֵל, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהִיא שָׁטָה עַל פְּנֵי הַמַּיִם, מֻתָּר לִכָּנֵס בָּהּ.
>
> One is allowed to enter a boat if it is resting on the ground (bed) of the sea and is not floating at all. If it is tied as is customary with boats docked in a port, even though it is floating on the water, one is allowed to enter it.

As far as riding along even when e.g. a non-Jew will be sailing the boat, this is a potential problem even when one boarded before Shabbat if one would still be on board on Shabbat (see Shabbat 19a cited [here](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-trav-cruise.htm)).

(These laws are true for both Shabbat and Yom Tov. As noted by @DoubleAA, there may also be an issue of *techum shabbat*, if one were to travel more than ~3100 feet, since a lake generally doesn't have residences on the water. Also, with regard to Yom Kippur, there is an additional issue of getting wet in a way which might be considered *taanug*.)

(See also [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/tues_02_12_13/) and [here](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=1594).)

Comment: The verb "שט" AFAIK implies movement and does not include floating in place. Cf. "_shatu haam v'lak'tu_".

Comment: @msh210 That's a fair point. However, my understanding is that שט means to float (as in modern Hebrew) which may or may not also include movement (as in English). Contextually, the whole point of the Shulchan Aruch's law is to suggest that it is the movement that is the problem and floating is only allowed when the movement is not significant, as is the case when the boats are docked כְּמִנְהַג הַסְפִינוֹת הָעוֹמְדוֹת בַּנָּמֵל. The OP was asking about taking a boat out on a lake which clearly is not allowed based on the Mechaber's wording.

Comment: @msh210 Further, the Mechaber is discussing *entering*, certainly not "paddling".

Answer (score 2):

One may do so, provided it's tied to something on the shore. [Obviously, he won't get very far.] *Shulchan Aruch* 339:7. However, see the commentaries there for details and exceptions. And, if this is a practical question for you, ask your rabbi rather than relying on what you read on this site.

Note that there's no explicit prohibition on "traveling", though various methods of travel are prohibited for various reasons. Boarding and traveling by a boat is (with an exception outlined above) among them.

Comment: And be careful not to violate techum.

Comment: The Shulchan Aruch there is talking about entering it without causing it to move around. The implication is that "paddling around" would be completely forbidden.

Comment: @Loewian, I don't see that there. See my comment on your answer.