# Can I take a row boat out on shabbos/ yom tov which is within an eruv?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work

Over shabbos and yom tov I'll be staying somewhere which has a small lake and row boats which are within an eruv. I don't know enough about the issue to understand, is it forbidden to take out such a row boat on shabbos and/or yom tov for enjoyment? Or is it not forbidden, but "not in the spirit of" shabbos/yom tov?

I'm only able to find discussions about boarding ships on shabbos, but nothing about this situation which seems a little more nuanced...

Comment: https://asktherav.com/is-it-permissible-to-go-on-a-row-boat-canoe-or-paddle-boat-on-shabbos/

Comment: relevant (duplicate?): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/63840/11501

Comment: https://utj.org/viewpoints/responsa/paddle-boarding-on-yom-tov/

Comment: mbloch-- not a duplicate. I believe my scenario is unique in that the small lake is actually within an eruv, meaning I think it's more similar to the example of a pool in a courtyard which, from what I'm seeing, while swimming in a natural body of water may be assur, swimming in a pool in a courtyard may be allowed.