# Violating Shabbat in order to perform a mitzvah

Tags: halacha, shabbat, minyan

If a person lives too far away from shul to walk and feels compelled to drive in order to attend services on Shabbat, is this permissible according to halacha?

Comment: Hi Ephraim and welcome to Judaism! To directly answer your question, the proper approach to this is to talk to your Rabbi. It’s always much better to discuss personal halachic questions with your local orthodox Rabbi rather than a bunch of Internet strangers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Talmud (RH 32b) prohibits working on Rosh Hashana in order to get a Shofar, even though blowing Shofar on Rosh Hashana is a Mitzva, because there is both a positive ("rest!") and negative ("don't work!") aspect to the holiday. We don't push off one positive command for another when doing so also entails violating a negative command.

For Rosh Hashana the two relevant commandments are #310 and #311, and for Shabbat the two relevant commandments are #32 and #85 (as counted in Sefer HaChinukh).

Answer (score 4):

R. Nosson Nota Leiter has a responsum in which he critiques some of the responsa of [R. Yosef Messas](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%A9). He says that in responsum # 129 R. Messas allowed riding on the tramway in order to be able to pray with the congregation. R. Leiter says that if this ruling was issued in his country, the entire country would make fun of it, and as to the actual question they would tell the guy to stay home citing the verse:

> כִּי תָבֹאוּ לֵרָאוֹת פָּנָי מִי בִקֵּשׁ זֹאת מִיֶּדְכֶם רְמֹס חֲצֵרָי
>
> When ye come to appear before Me, who hath required this at your hand,
>   to trample My courts? ([Mechon Mamre](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1001.htm))

**[Shu"t Tziyun L'nefesh Chaya Siman 29](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7505&st=&pgnum=70&hilite=)**

> מש"כ בסימן קכ"ט להתיר ליסע על טראמוויי למען יתפלל בצבור ידע אם היה
>   הלכה זו במדינתינו היו לועזין ע"ז כל המדינה ואם יבוא שאלה כזו לפנינו
>   היינו משיבים לשואל הכבד ושב בביתך כי הפרוץ מרובה על העומד בתפלה מי
>   ביקש זאת מידך רמוס חצרי

Interestingly, it does not appear that R. Messas actually issued the ruling that R. Leiter cites. In his reponsa, Shu"t Mayim Chaim, he deals with various forms of travel on Shabbos in simanim 126-132. There he discusses, respectively, riding on an animal, riding in a wagon, riding a bicycle, riding in an automobile, riding on a train, riding on an airplane, and riding on a boat. For each mode of travel he notes the possible Shabbos problems, and for most of them he is stringent. He does not appear to discuss the question of whether it is permissible when going to pray with the congregation. (In the first responsum he discusses traveling to do a circumcision, and he forbids it, but in the rest of the responsa he just discusses whether the mode of travel is in general Shabbos-compliant. Even when he mentions how to technically avoid actual Shabbos-violation he still says it shouldn't be done, except for airplane and boat.)

Links to the 7 responsa:

- [126](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1911&st=&pgnum=131&hilite=) (animal)
- [127](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1911&st=&pgnum=134) (wagon)
- [128](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1911&st=&pgnum=134) (bicycle)
- [129](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1911&st=&pgnum=134) (automobile)
- [130](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1911&st=&pgnum=134) (train)
- [131](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1911&st=&pgnum=134) (airplane)
- [132](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1911&st=&pgnum=134) (boat)

Another responsum related to this issue was penned by [R. Yair Chaim Bachrach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yair_Bacharach). He was asked about someone who lived across the river from the congregation and wanted to know if he was allowed to cross it on Shabbos in order to go pray.

R. Bachrach discusses various issues at length, but his conclusion is that one cannot even override any rabbinic prohibition in order to get to the congregation, even if they will have no minyan without him (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26954/13438) for a lengthier discussion of this responsum):

**[Shu"t Chavos Yair Siman 115](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=857&pgnum=132)**

> סוף דבר נראה שאין להקל בשום ענין להתיר שום גזירה דרבנן בעסק מצוה ללמוד
>   ממקום אחר ולדמות מילתא למילתא ובכה"ג ארז"ל והאחרונים בשבותין ובנדרים
>   שהתירו חכמים ובירושלמי במלאכות שהתירו בחש"מ  ואפילו בביטול מצוה דרבים
>   ובר"ה לא נ"ל להתיר ליחיד לבא בספינה להשלים מנין ולתקוע ולהתפלל ברבים
>   אע"פ שיש כאן ביטול כמה מצות דאין לנו מאזני צדק בזה אף כי ארז"ל בהדיא
>   שופר של ר"ה אין מעבירין וכו' ואמרו מפני די"ט עשה ול"ת ואע"פ דשם התירו
>   לומר לגוי יש לחלק בספינה ההולכת בשבילו וראיה מיושב בקרון סופג את
>   הארבעים ע' תשובה  נ"ל

Answer (score 1):

I found the following text, reporting a very special situation in Moscow in 5742.

> הרב משה פינשטיין (מפי נכדו ר' מרדכי טנדלר), (נמסר ע"י הרב פנחס
>   גולדשמיט "זיכרון בספר", סימן י"ג)
>
> במוסקבה אין שכונה מיוחדת ליהודים... וכעת ב"ה הנה ימים באו ..ורבים
>   מאחינו בני ישראל, אשר לא ידעו בין ימינם לשמאלם באים ודופקים בשערי
>   מקדשי מעט, ורוצים להנות מזיו השכינה בשבת קודש. אד דא עקא, שבכל מוסקבה
>   יש רק שבעה מקומות אשר בהם מתפללים בציבור...ואין אפשרות לספק לכל הבאים
>   מקום לינה ליד מקום התפילה בשבת ויש אשר גרים במרחק כמה וכמה פרסאות. אשר
>   על כן נשאלתי; האם מותר להזמין אנשים כאשר ידוע שקרוב לוודאי יסעו ברכבת
>   התחתית כדי לבוא להתפלל?"... השיב מר סבי בשנת תשמ"ב, אפילו אם יש איזה
>   איסור בדבר, אין למחות בידי הרוצים לנסוע ברכבת לילך לבית הכנסת, לשמוע
>   תקיעת שופר, ליטול לולב ואתרוג ולאכל בסוכה, ואין להגיד מאומה כנגדם, בין
>   לגבי שבת בין לגבי יום טוב, דעדיף שיהו יהודים שיהיה להם התקשרות לתורה
>   ומצוות משניתן להם תוכחה אל אי זהירות במצווה"

It seems that Rav Moshe Feinstein zatzal gave the heter to invite people for Shabbos who were likely to travel on the underground when there were many people seeking out Judaism, only 7 shuls in Moscow and insufficient places to lodge overnight visitors for Shabbos.

Comment: But this is not the same situation - inviting people who would anyway transgress Shabbat or transgressing yourself - is very different!